# InputStream to JsonObject - GSON

Tags: java, android, gson

I've a lot of trouble converting a result from this api to a JsonObject.

The "result" stays null no matter what I try to do.

```
  URL url = new URL(urlString);
  InputStream input = url.openStream();
  Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
  JsonResult result  = new Gson().fromJson(reader, JsonResult.class);
```

JsonResult class

```
public class JsonResult {
    private String status;
    private Meta meta;
    private ArrayList<Player> players;
}

class Meta{
    private String count;
}
```

Json:

```
{"status":"ok","meta":{"count":12},"data":[{"nickname":"DataBase","account_id":500566109},{"nickname":"database007","account_id":514382449},{"nickname":"Database04","account_id":504367425},{"nickname":"database08","account_id":515081772},{"nickname":"database1","account_id":503282284},{"nickname":"database1221","account_id":506709044},{"nickname":"database123","account_id":508409172},{"nickname":"database1337","account_id":501661259},{"nickname":"database169","account_id":503884400},{"nickname":"database2","account_id":504337382},{"nickname":"database93","account_id":518691821},{"nickname":"databaseking66","account_id":505911069}]}
```

Note: This is for a school project

Note 2: I did check and test a lot of other solutions from SO but didn't find or understand the correct one.

Edit 1:

```
public class JsonResult {
    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;
    @SerializedName("meta")
    public Meta meta;
    @SerializedName("data")
    public Player[] players;
}

class Meta{
    @SerializedName("count")
    private String count;
}
```

Player class

```
public class Player {

    private int account_id;
    private String nickname;

    public Player(int account_id, String nickname){
        this.account_id = account_id;
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }


    //Generated
    public void setAccount_id(int account_id) {
        this.account_id = account_id;
    }

    //Generated
    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.account_id + this.nickname;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you've "a lot of trouble" - well what happens? Does that code compile? Is there an exception? What does the JSON look like?

Comment: @Jochem third party links are frowned upon, due to their dynamic nature (someone may click the link in the future and won't find anything helpful). Your post must be edited to include everything relevant.

_Also some of us are behind workplace firewalls ;)_

Comment: @Trobbins thanks, it will be there in a moment :). I've edited the question

Comment: your players are apparently called `data`. Either change it or add an annotation to indicate that to Gson.

Comment: @njzk2 does the edit looks correct? all new for me, currently testing and debugging everything

Comment: @JochemQuery: yep, looks good (@SerializedName is not mandatory on all fields, but it also protects you from Proguard obfuscation and minification)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your JsonResult class change

```
public class JsonResult {
    private String status;
    private Meta meta;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private ArrayList<Player> players;
}
```

Comment: It's important to describe _why_ this is the solution. The reason is that Gson tries to map attributes by their name, and the attribute name for the Array of players in JSON is "data", and there was no attribute with a name of "data" in the JsonResult class, therefore it couldn't find a place to put it and would omit it.

This annotation tells the parser to use the 'players' field when it sees the "data" attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @DaveLugg and the answer -Ads. There is something still giving me a null error. I'm rereading my code and trying again

Comment: Can you post your Player class ?

Comment: @Ads Done, Am I missing "correct" getters and setters?

Comment: I think is not a good idea using the POJO attributes with a different name of the origin JSON attributes, the @SerializedName annotation it should be necessary only if you have no control over the JSON source, a POJO with the same attribute names than JSON attributes has better readability. Another thing, using the List interface instead of an implementation class is better.

Comment: @vzamanillo thank you for your comment, i've no control over this JSON source. I will use a interface now

Comment: You're welcome, anyway you always can name the List as "data" instead of "players", then you dont need the annotation anymore.

Comment: @vzamanillo aah offcourse, I should stop coding when tired :)

Comment: @vzamanillo Having the annotation there means that he can access his players List anywhere and people won't get confused about what it's about. If he uses 'data' for his field, then he might iterate over it later in the code and someone looking in will not know what "data" represents.

Naming variables after what they contain is a good practice that should be followed.

JochemQuery It is up to you, of course, but I would leave it on. Every time you access the players array later on in the code it's easier to understand what it's referring to.